# How can I solve my "sub main was not found" problem?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Module PrimePairs
    Public Function IsPrime(n As Long) As Boolean
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value: ")
        n = Console.ReadLine()
        n = Math.Abs(n) ' Allows to consider negative prime numbers
        If n < 2 Then   ' Disallows -1, 0, 1
            Return False
        End If

        Dim i As Long
        i = 2
        While i < n ' Note that for n = 2 we don't enter the loop and thus return True.
            If n Mod i = 0 Then
                Return False
            End If
            i += 1
        End While
        Return True
    End Function
    Public Function PrimePairs(ByVal n As Long, ByVal n2 As Long) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Console.ReadLine()
        If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To (n / 2) + 1
                n2 = n - i
                If IsPrime(i) And IsPrime(n2) = True Then
                    count += 1
                End If
            Next

        Else
            n2 = n - 2
            If IsPrime(n2) = True Then
                count = +1
            End If

        End If

        Console.WriteLine("The result is:", count)
        Return n
    End Function


End Module
```

I want my code to calculate how many prime number twins can write the input I gave.

Comment: When you say "I tried all solutions" can you please let us know what you tried?

Comment: Tip for Stack Overflow: titles should be a useful and succinct summary of the problem. If this contains chatty or needy material the question becomes a target for downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your project actually does not contain a `Sub Main()`, as the error states.

You defined two functions in the `Module Program`, but console applications need a predefined entry point, which usually is the Main method.

The compiler is telling you that your project is not valid because it didn't find any entry point.

Just add a `Sub Main()` to get your project working, then call your functions from that method.

Example:

```
Option Strict On

Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value: ")
        Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim number As Long
        If Long.TryParse(input, number) Then // More about this function in the answer below
            Dim prime As Boolean = IsPrime(number)
            If prime Then
                Console.WriteLine(number & " is prime.")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(number & " is not prime.")
            End If
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Function IsPrime(n As Long) As Boolean
        n = Math.Abs(n) ' Allows to consider negative prime numbers
        If n < 2 Then   ' Disallows -1, 0, 1
            Return False
        End If
        Dim i As Long = 2
        i = 2
        While i < n ' Note that for n = 2 we don't enter the loop and thus return True.
            If n Mod i = 0 Then
                Return False
            End If
            i += 1
        End While
        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

Also, I suggest you to enable **Option Strict On** as I added at the beginning of file. This prevents the compiler from doing implicit casts and forces you to explicitly declare your variables.

E.g., your line of code

```
n = Console.ReadLine()
```

is not valid with `Option Strict On`, because `n` is supposed to be a `long`, but `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`.

If you are a beginner, this will allow you to better understand how programming works and will help you to avoid errors - take good habits from the beginning, you can thank me later ;)

That's why I changed your code with`Long.TryParse(input, number)`: this function returns `true` if provided input can be cast (=converted) to a `long`, and assigns the casted value to `number` variable.

There's a lot more I'd like to suggest you, but I would go off-topic.